# Experience with Windows Server 2008 R2 Print Management for large quantities of printers

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing, print-server

I have to manage around one hundred printers and I'm looking for ways to centralize all the printers in one printer server. I have been looking into Windows Server 2008 R2 Printer Management service. Do you have any experience with this service? Do you know if it can handle this quantity of printers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can easily handle that amount of printers.

You could even do it as a vm with that amount of printers. We have a 2008R2 printer server with over 300 printers on it running in hyper-v.